# File sharing websoftware for linux

Tags: linux, file-management

I want to host a small file sharing site for my friends to quickly share pictures/files/documents etc.

The simply way I can imagine this, is when visiting the website on my server, you get asked for a password (No user password, just a password in general). After that it should just be a simple drag and drop to upload something and get a sharable link for that file. Also there should be a setting in the software that auto deletes files after X days.

The simpler, the better.

Is there a simple software for linux that could do exactly that?

Comment: Back in the days the Opera Browser included this. I think it was called Unity. Good times. Nowadays, take a look here: https://github.com/mayfrost/guides/blob/master/ALTERNATIVES.md#filesharing

Answer (score 1):

Check out OwnCloud (https://owncloud.com/download-server/)

Just use the non-enterprise version and it's Free.

It won't auto-delete files, but it will automatically remove access to those files after X number of days.